# How to solve two-point boundary nonlinear ordinary differential equations （ODEs）with free final time numerically?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve two-point boundary nonlinear ordinary differential equations (ODEs) with free final time. I have failed many times to apply Mathematica to solve this problem and would really appreciate if someone can give me an answer.

Given variables: `v=1; w=0.00003; r=0.0002; {xo,yo} = {20,20}`:

The ODEs are:

```
x'[t] ==vCos[q[t]]+wx[t]+ry[t]+(x[t]-xo)/((x[t]-xo)^2+(y[t]-yo)^2)^(3/2);
y'[t] ==vSin[q[t]]-rx[t]+wy[t]+(y[t]-yo)/((x[t]-xo)^2+(y[t]-yo)^2)^(3/2);
q'[t] ==-r+3(Cos[q[t]^2]-Sin[q[t]^2])(x[t]-xo)(y[t]-yo)/((x[t]-xo)^2+(y[t]-yo)^2)^(5/2)+
    3Cos[q[t]]Sin[q[t]]((y[t]-yo)^2-(x[t]-xo)^2)/((x[t]-xo)^2+(y[t]-yo)^2)^(5/2);
```

where `x'[t]`, `y'[t]` are the known motion dynamics of the system and `q'[t]` is the evolution of control law which is already known too. Given an initial known condition [x[t=0], y[t=0]]=[0,0] and the final target condition `{x[t=tf], y[t=tf]} = {100,100}` where the final time `tf` is unknown, the question is how to find the initial control input `q[t=0]` which makes the system situation changes from the initial condition `{0,0}` to the final target condition `{100,100}` with the minimal time `tf`?

Comment: Please provide the actual equations, so that readers can experiment with them.  Be sure to write them in Mathematica format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I have given the detailed equations, please help me on solving the problem. Looking forwards to hearing from you.

Comment: Is `vCos` a free parameter or should it be `v*Cos[q[t]]`? Note `Cos(x)` means `Cos` ***times*** `x`, which is almost never what is wanted.

Comment: You are right that it represents v*Cos[q[t]], please help me on solving this problem.

Comment: I have tried the shooting method to solve this problem where the initial control input 'q[t=0] ' ranges from [0 2*pi]. However, I don't know how to formulate the problem to Mathematica form when applying the shooting method as the final time 'tf' is unknown.  @ bbgodfrey @ Michael E2

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a answer. If not, I would increase the variable 'v' in the equations to have a try. @ bbgodfrey

Comment: I'm not very sure that there is a solution for all kinds of constant variable 'v'. But under the setup, the solutions deed exist for some intial and final conditions.  If not, I would increase the variable 'v' in the equations to have a try. You can have a try on different intial and final conditions, thanks. @ bbgodfrey

Comment: I hope you will become a regular contributor to Mathematica.SE.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the integration as follows:

```
eq = {x'[t] == v Cos[q[t]] + w x[t] + 
        r y[t] + (x[t] - xo)/((x[t] - xo)^2 + (y[t] - yo)^2)^(3/2), 
      y'[t] == v Sin[q[t]] - r x[t] + 
        w y[t] + (y[t] - yo)/((x[t] - xo)^2 + (y[t] - yo)^2)^(3/2), 
      q'[t] == -r + 3 (Cos[q[t]^2] - Sin[q[t]^2]) (x[t] - xo) (y[t] - yo)/((x[t] - xo)^2 + 
        (y[t] - yo)^2)^(5/2) + 3 Cos[q[t]] Sin[q[t]] ((y[t] - yo)^2 - 
        (x[t] - xo)^2)/((x[t] - xo)^2 + (y[t] - yo)^2)^(5/2)}

tmax = 300;
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq /. {v -> 1, w -> 3 10^-5, r -> 2 10^-4, xo -> 20, yo -> 20},
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, q[0] == q0}, {x, y, q}, {t, 0, tmax}, {q0}];
```

Then, the answer is

```
sol = FindRoot[(Through[s[q0][tf]] - 100)[[1 ;; 2]], {tf, 140}, {q0, .88}, Evaluated -> False]
(* {tf -> 141.238, q0 -> 0.885835} *)
```

I obtained the initial guesses by plotting `s[q0]` for various values of `test`, for instance.

```
test = 140; 
Plot[{Through[s[q0][test]][[1]] - 100, Through[s[q0][test]][[2]] - 100}, {q0, 0.8, 1}]
```

[image]

For completeness, here is a `Plot` of the integrated functions with parameters that satisfy the desired boundary conditions.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[s[q0][t] /. sol], {t, 0, tf /. sol}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x, y, q"}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

In response to comments below, a slightly more efficient approach is

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq /. {v -> 1, w -> 3 10^-5, r -> 2 10^-4, xo -> 20, yo -> 20},
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, q[0] == q0}, {x, y, q}, {t, 0, tf}, {q0, tf}];
sol = Quiet@FindRoot[(Through[s[q0, tf][tf]] - 100)[[1 ;; 2]], 
    {tf, 140}, {q0, 1.0}, Evaluated -> False]
(* {tf -> 141.238, q0 -> 0.885835} *)
```

as before.  (`Quiet` has been added to suppress unimportant error messages produced when guesses are not so good.)  Interestingly, a second solution also exists.

```
sol = Quiet@FindRoot[(Through[s[q0, tf][tf]] - 100)[[1 ;; 2]], 
    {tf, 140}, {q0, 0.6}, Evaluated -> False]
(* {tf -> 141.379, q0 -> 0.711415} *)
```

`tf` is slightly larger for this second solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution. What does  Evaluated -> False mean and the purpose of the usage of tmax?  @bbgodfrey

Comment: ` Evaluated -> False` prevents `FindRoot` from trying to evaluate `s` without inserting numerical values.  `tmax` is just an upper bound on the integration that I chose to be large enough that `tf` was likely to be less than `tmax`.

Comment: Great appreciation for your help. In that case, I need to choose a large engough tmax when I solve the ODEs with different initial and final conditions. Thanks again for your code and I will have a try on it for different initial and final conditions. @ bbgodfrey

Comment: @JohnBai  In response to your last comment, I modified the code slightly to eliminate the need to guess `tmax`.  In the process, I noticed a second solution at smaller `q0`.  It has a slightly larger value of `tf`, so the original solution still is the one you wanted.  However, you need to be aware that there may be two solutions when running different parameters.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I tried to use the code on different initial and final conditions. It works well except that for each case the initial guess on test and q0 should be conducted. Thanks for your reply. @bbgodfrey